# How to find optimal measurement for quantum states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

If we are given two state $\rho_0$ and $\rho_1$, given a random state of the state without knowing which one it is, how can one generally give the optimal measurement strategy to distinguish them?

For example, for
$\rho_0 = |0\rangle\langle0|$ and $\rho_1 = (1/2)( |0\rangle\langle0|+|1 \rangle\langle 1| )$

Intuively one can say the optimal measurement is the computational basis and it succeds in distinguishing the states with probability $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{trace-distance(\rho_0,\rho_1)}{2} $ so $3/4$.

But how does one prove the intuitive choice? and how do we find it in general for any 2 given density matrices, for example what if $\rho_1 = (1/2)( |0\rangle\langle0|+|+ \rangle\langle +| )$

What is the easiest way to find the optimal measurement in that case?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "optimal" exactly?

Comment: @hft the one that maximises the probability of being able to distinguish the states $\rho_0$ from $\rho_1$

Comment: It seems like if I can find an operator that is zero for one of the expectation values, then I can distinguish 100% of  the time. For example, in the provided example, you could measure $|1><1|$.

Comment: see eg https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4164/55 and https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/21339/55. The latter contains in particular a proof of this result

Comment: also, to clarify the above comments: the trace distance appears when one asks for the measurement that gives the optimal *average* success probability of guessing the state correctly. One could also ask what is the best discrimination probability imposing also zero error probability, which is in general smaller than the optimal discrimination probability mentioned above)